# How to remove overlapping stroke

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm trying to draw an array of circles that are supposed to break an array of lines.
Everything looks good if circles are far away from each other, but if the circles overlap - a stroke appears underneath.

Any tips on how to remove this stroke when circles overlap?
Here's what I'm talking about:

[image]

Here is my code:

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas')
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#121212";
ctx.lineWidth = 1;
ctx.fillStyle = '#121212';
ctx.strokeStyle = '#9f9999';
ctx.lineCap = "round";

let width = canvas.width;
let height = canvas.height;

let lines = new Array(height);
let singleLine = new Array(width);
let step = 30;

for (let y = step; y < height; y += step) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  for (let x = step; x < width; x += step) {

    if (Math.random() < 0.85) {
      ctx.lineTo(x, y);
    } else {
      drawCircle(y, x);
    }
  }
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.fill();
}


function drawCircle(x, y) {
  ctx.arc(y, x, 20, Math.PI, 0, false);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: The best would be to not rely on `fill()` to hide the intersection and instead calculate precisely where your arcs should start and end. This implies generating all the commands first and then search for the intersection points, to finally convert these to angles to use in ctx.arc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because your way of covering the intersection through `fill()` will cover *only* half of the stroke on the fill area's border. This is okay-ish for the rounded part, but the bottom (implicit) `lineTo` between both arcs will still have its bottom half visible:

```js
const ctx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.25)";

ctx.lineTo(30, 50);
ctx.lineTo(60, 50);
ctx.arc(90, 50, 20, Math.PI, 0);
ctx.arc(120, 50, 20, Math.PI, 0);
ctx.lineTo(150, 50);
ctx.lineTo(180, 50);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.fill();

// a zoomed in version in case it's not visible enough
const zoom = document.querySelectorAll("canvas")[1].getContext("2d");
zoom.scale(4, 4);
zoom.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
zoom.drawImage(ctx.canvas, -70, -20);
```

```css
canvas{ vertical-align: middle }
```

```html
<canvas width=200></canvas>zoomed in: <canvas></canvas>
```

My original thought was to draw rectangles over each overlapping bump section, but a better approach was [suggested in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71586093/how-to-remove-overlapping-stroke/71590960?noredirect=1#comment126537721_71590960): extend the fill slightly downward after stroking, then fill the path with the background color. This ensures the bottom stroke of the overlapping lines are filled as well.

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas")
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#121212";
ctx.lineWidth = 1;
ctx.fillStyle = "#121212";
ctx.strokeStyle = "#9f9999";
ctx.lineCap = "round";

const {width, height} = canvas;
const step = 30;

for (let y = step; y < height; y += step) {
  ctx.beginPath();

  for (let x = step; x < width; x += step) {
    if (Math.random() < 0.55) {
      ctx.lineTo(x, y);
    }
    else {
      ctx.arc(x, y, 20, Math.PI, 0, false);
    }
  }

  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.lineTo(width - step, y + 1);
  ctx.lineTo(step, y + 1);
  //ctx.fillStyle = "red"; // to debug
  ctx.fill();
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: OP's use of `fill()` to hide the intersection is already an hack anyway. A maybe easier and safer one would be `... ctx.stroke(); ctx.lineTo(width - step, y + 10); ctx.lineTo(step, y + 10); ctx.fill();` though. This will ensure that the fill area covers also the "base" stroke in the arcs. (Ps: A small explanation of what happens would aslo be a plus for such an answer.)

Comment: Yep, that makes much more sense. Updated to use that approach! Feel free to add more details (it's a community wiki now), but I thought the explanation of "draw rectangles over the unwanted lines" was sufficient to explain my original strategy.

Comment: Oh you didn't have to make it a CW, but alright, I wrote a little something to explain what happens.